# Storing and loading Map markers with Map Fragment in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-markers

How do I store and load markers placed on a particular Map Fragment so that when the application is closed and reopened the data exists. Should I create a Sqlite table that stores these markers(the latitude and longitude of them and other associated info) or is there some other process I can use?

When the markers are tapped an associated activity with particular data needs to open and load certain data. How can I uniquely identify this activity data with a particular marker so that the correct data is loaded when tapped?
Any help on this conceptual question and possibly some code would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should consider 2 things:

- saving the state of which marker was tapped, the current zoom and position...well all the UI stuff to be "persisted"
- create a sqllite database with your data would be a great benefit (after the pain of creating it of course). I used ActiveAndroid but there are plenty of other solution out there ORMLite seems great

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to add marker and store there latitude and longitude. Without adding latitude and longitude you can not add marker. when you add marker to google map then you can also store latitude and longitude to your.

```
    double lat = 21.6335441;
    double log = 54.8701203;
       Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
       .position(new LatLng(lat,log ))
       .title("India"));
```

now u can store lat,log